# Reference on subcategories of ${\bf Rel}$

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory

> Is there a reference discussing the 'canonical' subcategories of ${\bf Rel}$?

By 'canonical subcategories' I mean the categories  $${\bf EntRel},$$ $${\bf FunRel},$$ $${\bf SurRel},$$ $${\bf InjRel},$$ whose arrows are entire relations, functional relations, surjective relations and injective relations, respectively. As a starting observation, the sentences defining entire-ness and functionality are dual to the ones defining surjectivity and injectivity (respectively) -- as a consequence of this, $${\bf EntRel}^{op}\cong{\bf SurRel},$$ $${\bf FunRel}^{op}\cong{\bf InjRel}.$$

We can mix-and-match these properties to obtain further canonical subcategories $${\bf Set},$$ $${\bf InjSurRel},$$ $${\bf FunSurRel},$$ $${\bf EntInjRel},$$ $${\bf EntSurRel},$$ $${\bf FunInjRel},$$ whose arrows are suggested by their names, and the above observations descend to say that $${\bf Set}^{op}\cong{\bf InjSurRel}\ (\simeq{\bf Bool}),$$ $${\bf FunSurRel}^{op}\cong{\bf EntInjRel},$$ $${\bf EntSurRel}^{op}\cong{\bf EntSurRel},$$ $${\bf FunInjRel}^{op}\cong {\bf FunInjRel},$$
and further ${\bf EntSurRel}$ and ${\bf FunInjRel}$ both inherit the dagger structure of ${\bf Rel}$. We can obviously go further to obtain the categories $${\bf EntFunInjRel}\ (=Mono({\bf Set})),$$ $${\bf EntFunSurRel}\ (=Epi({\bf Set})),$$ $${\bf FunInjSurRel},$$ $${\bf EntInjSurRel},$$ and finally $${\bf EntFunInjSurRel}\ (=Core({\bf Set})).$$

We have an obvious 'web' of forgetful inclusions as below (pardon the sloppiness)

[image]

and I'm curious which of them have left/right adjoints. It should be possible to use the adjoint functor theorems (or failure of preservation of limits/colimits) to check for adjoints (or lack of adjoints, resp.), but I haven't sat down and worked it out yet.

The motivation here was originally to better understand ${\bf EntSurRel}$ as a dagger category, since the domain/codomain relations in the one hom-class definition of a category are most naturally considered as entire surjective relations, but it's kind of fun to play with these subcategories in general and I'd be curious to read more on the subject. Any relevant input or references are appreciated.